# How to manage images on Docker Hub when images are pushed to hub on every successful build in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, dockerhub, docker-image

I am using microservice-based architecture and separate pipelines are built for every microservice. 
I am using Docker BuildandPush as a stage in Azure build pipeline and on every successful build, images are being pushed to DockerHub.

**Now, My main concern is with time my DockerHub registry is filling with redundant images, so how do I clear those redundant images automatically through any pipeline stage or script?**

Comment: Can you please add your tagging strategy? Are you pushing an image with a unique tag in each pipeline?  or for every branch, you are pushing one image?

Comment: For every microservice/branch, images are pushed with a unique tag according to build Id. @Ashwani

Comment: is branch-name included in docker image/tag? or just build-id?

Comment: This is the tag by which images are pushed on DockerHub repository: branchName-$(Build.BuildId) @Ashwani

Comment: Suggestion: You can write a script/cronjob which deletes all the tags for a branch except last 3 or any number.

Comment: Can you please share a reference for the same.@Ashwani

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an image through registry REST API . For this, you need to know the docker image name and the digest you want to delete. An image may be deleted from the registry via its `name` and `reference`,`reference` must be a digest or the delete will fail.

Invoke rest API:

```
DELETE http://registryhost:reigstryport/v2/<docker_image_name>/manifests/<reference>
```

For example:

```
curl -v -X DELETE https://my.docker.registry.com:5000/v2/mytestdockerrepo/manifests/sha256:66675d81b9bd5eafc105832b78abb91cab975bbcf028ca4bce4afe73f66914ee
```

You should get a 202 Accepted for a successful invocation. If the image had already been deleted or did not exist, a 404 Not Found response will be issued instead.

**Note** When deleting a manifest from a registry version 2.3 or later, the following header must be used when HEAD or GET-ing the manifest to obtain the correct digest to delete:

```
Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
```

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#deleting-an-image).